# Cannot find XAMPP software in startup menu

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP in my computer. After completing installation it is automatically opened. It was totally working. I closed XAMPP and then try to find it in my start menu it is not showing anywhere. Please help me to find it.

Comment: Go to the directory where you installed XAMPP?

Comment: I think this is going to be Microsoft, but it doesn't state it clearly enough.